# Django form models | ComboBox value

Tags: django

How do I get the selected value from a form's ComboBox field? what is the model class that deals with ComboBoxes? ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a ComboBox in Django (or in HTML). I assume you are talking about a `ChoiceField`, which renders a `select` control in HTML.

You access the value of a ChoiceField in exactly the same way as any other field, once the form has been submitted and validated - by accessing `form.cleaned_data['fieldname']`.

You should read the [excellent documentation on forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that, and yes it can be access in that but how can I define the ChoiceField in my model.There;s no attribute called ChoiceField in models.

Comment: No, ChoiceField is a form field, not a model field.

Comment: So how do I use a select control with Django models.. ?

Comment: There is another SO question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463700/django-combobox

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @MMRUser, the `ChoiceField` is the form class to achieve an HTML `select` element.

But for the model itself, you can pass the [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) argument to a model field (typically a `CharField`) which will result in the `ModelForm` using an HTML `select` element.