# Django select options

Tags: python, django, forms, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm making an app that has a file name field, an upload file field and a select. Lets say I have something like this for the select

```
<select name="menu">
   <option value="0" selected> select imp </option>
   <option value="1"> imp 1 </option>
   <option value="2"> imp 2 </option>
   <option value="3"> imp 3 </option>
   <option value="4"> imp 4 </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

I have the file upload working with this class

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput())
```

How should the class look with the select added to it?
Or how can I use the file upload form and get the value from the select, and based on that value do an action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a [ChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

```
IMP_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'imp 1'),
    ('2', 'imp 2'),
    ('3', 'imp 3'),
    ('4', 'imp 4'),
)

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput())
    imp = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IMP_CHOICES)
```

Comment: ahh so django had a choice field after all :) 

Thx a lot m8.

Regards void,

Comment: Link above is broken, but  it seems that the current solution is the "choices" parameter in a "CharField", docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices)